# Downloading videos and saving to camera roll?

Tags: video, jailbreak, data-transfer, camera

I need a tweak like "Download Manager pro", which allows you to download any video you play.
The thing is, it saves to its own private storage (and not camera roll) so I can't share them with anyone.

Does anyone knows a tweak that does this job?

Comment: What is a tweak and what does this run on?

Comment: @Mark Since this question has a "jailbreak" tag, I believe Andrei is referring to extensions installable on jailbroken iOS devices.

Comment: @britta - The "jailbreak" tag was not put by Andrei.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tweaks for jailbroken iOS that can import videos into the Videos app:

- [Music2iPod](http://modmyi.com/content/8961-import-media-media-applications-music2ipod.html) (free). I haven't tested this one though.
- [Bridge](http://modmyi.com/content/8843-import-media-files-your-media-libraries-bridge.html) ($2).
- The paid version of [iFile](http://iphone.heinelt.eu/?Applications%3aiFile) ($4), using the Gremlin library.
- [YourTube](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/13/yourtube-for-ios6-available/) ($4) also uses the Gremlin library and lets you import videos directly from the YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

Titan Downloader (Video Download & Player - Titan Downloader) (app store app) lets you use browser inside the app & when you click on a video, you can save it to cache on the app & when you click on the videos tab you can save the video to camera roll or just keep it in the app, your choice.

I personally bought the pro because it is worth it in all honesty. Can save more videos.

Answer (score -2):

Use MediaBurner, you can download and transfer your video in the camera roll

Answer (score -3):

you can download form cydia universale video downloader